# Is it possible to have multiple seller PayPal accounts a la eBay? (ASP.NET MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal

First of all I'd like to apologize for writing this here. PayPal's forum do not let me create a new post. And the

I tried looking in these places:
(This is the same question I'm having, but can't seem to find an answer to it)
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/Multi-Vendor-Site-and-how-to-use-Paypal/td-p/36855

Even tried looking here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

And read this:
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/About-Business/Developers-looking-for-help-Please-read/m-p/426651#U426651

And then, it redirects me to eBay inc

Now, the real question:

I have a multi-vendor site. And I'd like to know if it's possible (and if it is, how to do this in ASP.NET MVC 5) to set up multiple PayPal seller accounts. What I mean, each vendor has its own paypal account by which he can receive his payment directly to it.

I don't know how to express this in Google terms, so I couldn't come up with a better solution.

Thanks a million!

Comment: You need to use PayPal for Marketplaces'. Look at the Connected Onboarding which is supposed to register your users with PayPal. I'm starting this too and I'm finding trouble finding a proper step-by-step tutorial for this.

Comment: @naz786: Thanks :). It's been a long time since I stopped working on the project related to the question. It's good to know, though.

Answer (score 1):

in your web.config

create section

```
<section name="PayPal" type="PaypalCredentials, Payment" />
```

and also create paypal section

```
<PayPal>
    <accounts>
        <account id="1" apiUsername="xxx.api1.com" apiPassword="yxy" apiSignature="asdasd" />
        <account id="2" apiUsername="yyy.api1.com" apiPassword="xyx" apiSignature="dasdas" />
    </accounts>  
</PayPal>
```

Then

You need to decide which account you will use before setexpresscheckout and also use the same credential info when you are making getexpresscheckoutresponse and doauthorization

There is also another way that you can give 3rd party authentication to one of the your account to another then when you are making request you need you put email address of given authenticated account in the subject area of paypal merchant credentials

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I don't know is how will this allow the sellers adapt their own PayPal accounts...