# PayPal .Net Invoice API multiple Accounts

Tags: c#, .net, paypal

I cant add multiple PayPal-Merchant-Accounts to my C# PayPal-API. I found this solution, but i get an error by name id field:
[Is it possible to have multiple seller PayPal accounts a la eBay? (ASP.NET MVC 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178662/)
Is it possible to send the API login details by the Paypal-Object?

Comment: You are saying that you have found "this solution" - I am not sure what you meant? Can you provide a reference or code?

Comment: In the answer. There are two PayPal-accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In the Invoice Service object you can choose this method:

`public CreateAndSendInvoiceResponse CreateAndSendInvoice(CreateAndSendInvoiceRequest createAndSendInvoiceRequest, string apiUserName);`

By combining the answer out of the link from my question (without id), I can now choose between many accounts.

**Edit**

Another solution:
https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-dotnet/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters